# Finding values based on keys separated by brackets

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a function that returns the value given a key stored in the string format below.

"[var1=x][var2=y][var3=z]"

My initial thought is to get the index of the var and add the length of the key to it for the starting index. Then I'll just grab the substring until the first occurrence of the closing square bracket which will give me the value. I'm fairly new to c++ and am wondering if I'm on the right track as far as thought process goes? Would it be better to instead create some sort of map instead?

Comment: Is `"[var1=x][var2=y][var3=z]"` equivalent to `"[var2=y][var3=z][var1=x]"`?

Comment: Until you have reached the end of the string, find the position of the next starting `[`, from that position find the terminating `]`. Get everything between as a separate sub-string (either copy the whole string or save it as a pair of positions, depending on use-case). Continue from the `]` to find the next `[`, and so on.

Comment: @StephenNewell Yes, the order doesn't matter since the string can contain any number of variables.

Comment: Then you make a type that you use as a key.  Stay far away from anything string-based.

Comment: Do you have control of the format? why wont you use normal JSON/INI/XML?

Comment: I have no control over the input, it's how the varchar is stored in the existing db. They've crammed all the variables in a single column and I now have to unpack them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `std::getline()`?

Here's some sample code:

```
struct Item
{
  std::string variable_name;
  std::string rhs_name;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Item& i);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Item& i)
{
    // Ignore until a '[' is found.
    input.ignore(10000, '[');

    // Read in variable name until '=' is found.
    std::getline(i.variable_name, '=');

    // Read in RHS name until ']' is found.
    std::getline(i.rhs_name, ']');

    return input;
}
```

*Note:  the `getline` eats the termination character.*

Usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>  

using std::cin;

int main()
{
  Item i;
  std::vector<Item> database;
  while (cin >> i)
  {
    database.push_back(i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```